# Can i use Window Remote Desktop to control user's screen without login?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, window, remote-control

Can i use Window Remote Desktop to control user's screen without login? maybe just prompt a message to ask user to allow the action. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Remote Assistance to control remote user's screen after getting permission

Comment: I have enabled the Remote Assistance but it still prompt me to login on that user

Comment: you need to run msra application to connect to remote machine. The logged in user on the remote machine will get prompt. Once accepted you will be able to see remote user's desktop.